# Vbscript to query old and large log files in C drive

Tags: vbscript

I have wrote a vbscript to query OldLogfiles and LargeLogfiles from C drive of the server and delete logs which is older than 6 months.But the script not seems to be working fine.I am not very good at scripting.Can anyone help me to fix the issue with below vbscript ?

```
strComputer = "."
Dim objFile,iDaysOld,item,objFSO,dateTime
Dim FileName,FileName1,Logs,GetFile,file
iDaysOld = 180
Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set files = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension='log' AND Drive='C:'")
For Each file in files
    If LCase(Right(Cstr(File.Name), 3)) = "log" Then
        FileName1 = Trim(File.Name)
        FileName = (File.Name & "," & FileName)
        wscript.echo FileName
        If file.LastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then
' oFile.Delete(True) 
            wscript.echo "tr_Oldlogfiles=" &FileName
        End If 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by 'not working'.

Comment: *not seems to be working* is not a problem description. How **exactly** is it *not working*?

Comment: The script is executing,but its not giving any output. Not sure which line of the script is having problem.

Comment: The script is executing and I am able to get entire log file details from C drive,But what I really want is the log file which is older than 180 days should print the results and Need to delete those files from C drive.its not giving that output.

Comment: looks like " If file.LastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then " is having problem

Comment: Do you have a `On Error Resume Next` line in the script? If so, comment it out and try again.

Comment: On Error Resume Next is not included in the script. The complete script is pasted above.

Comment: I have also tried in below Date Diff format as well.But it gives "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: '[string: "20150622114321.69096"]'"

Comment: If LCase(Right(Cstr(objFile.Name), 3)) = "log" Then

If DateDiff("d", objFile.LastModified, Date) >= iDaysOld Then